# Hiding loading image on asp.net postback for file download

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, events, dom

I have a button on my asp.net page that does a postback, creates an Excel file, clears the response stream and writes the file. The user can then open or save the file user the brower's standard dialog.

This works great, I based the code on this:

http://www.adventuresindevelopment.com/2009/05/27/how-to-export-data-to-excel-in-aspnet/

As the file to be created takes quite a long time I have created a loading panel, just a hidden DIV, and set this to visible when the button is clicked.

But my problem is how to hide this DIV when the export has finished? I just cannot find a way of doing it. I need something like an event that fires when the file has been completely transfered to the browser.

Is this possible? Any help most appreciated.

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do, long story short :

1. When the user clicks the "Download" button, use AJAX to call a
   processing page asynchronously. This page will generate your Excel
   document and store it in a temporary location
2. When the AJAX request is done, hide the "Loading" panel, and
   redirect the user to a download page. Ideally, you should redirect
   to a generic (.ashx) handler that opens the file, sets some headers,
   streams the temporary file to the user, and deletes the file
   afterwards.

Now in more details :

For step one, you should have some temporary folder where you have read and write access. Using the system temp folder is fine, so you could use `Path.GetTempFileName`. Here is an example of what you could write in an ashx handler :

```
public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string fName = Path.GetTempFileName();

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        try
        {
            // Generate the Excel document
            GenerateExcelInFile(fName);

            // Store the file name in session for later use
            context.Session["ExcelGeneratorFileName"] = fName;

            // Send confirmation to the client
            context.Response.Write("ok");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            context.Response.Write("error");
            // TODO : Do some logging
        }

    }

    // SNIP : IsReusable
}
```

After that, use your favorite JS framework to request that handler, and test the returned string. If it is "ok", you call the part two handler :

```
public class Handler2 : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

        // Make sure the browser will show a "save as" dialog to the user
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Export.pdf");

        string fName = context.Session["ExcelGeneratorFileName"] as String;

        if (fName != null && File.Exists(fName))
        {
            // Stream the excel file to the response
            context.Response.WriteFile(fName);

            // Remove the file
            File.Delete(fName);
        }
    }

    // SNIP : IsReusable
}
```

You can call this page in javascript simply using a `window.location = url`. The content-disposition header will tell the browser that this URL should not be displayed, only downloaded, so your user should stay on the download page.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer, I was trying not to use temporary files though, invariably some get left behind.